# Unable to import json file in spyder python with JSONDecodeError: Extra data

Tags: python

I'm new to python, I used the below code in spyder platform to parse the json file but it reflects an error.

```
import json

with open('D:/Py_Scrach/used_car_prices1.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    print(data)
```

Error:

```
runfile('C:/Users/sathishkumar.m/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/sathishkumar.m/.spyder-py3')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\sathishkumar.m\.spyder-py3\temp.py", line 10, in <module>
    data = json.load(f)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 340, in decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)

JSONDecodeError: Extra data
```

Comment: What are the contents of the JSON file?

Comment: it looks like you have wrong data in this file - it is not JSON - and it can't read it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

df1 = pd.read_json("D:/Py_Scrach/used_car_prices1.json",lines=True)

Comment: is this solution for your problem? If not then delete it. Stackoverflow is NOT forum. Here is place only for solutions, and if you have new details then put it in question.